# Force tasks that erred due to a Killed Worker to recompute

Tags: dask

Due to some cluster rules, it can happen that a process is killed for a given reason (e.g. being allocated in a node that has a high priority to another group of users)

Is there a way to make a task or dataset that was in that worker acquire the 'lost' tag such that the Dask/Distributed system re-runs that particular task as well as it's dependent graph?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to retry a failed task.  This is a reasonable request though, so I've opened a [Github issue here](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/852).  Future readers of this question may want to check on the status of that issue to see if things have changed.

Meanwhile, you can change a parameter that will avoid `KilledWorker` issues.  The `KilledWorker` exception only occurs if a task was actively running on three workers while they unexpectedly died.  This is meant to stop bad tasks from catastrophically taking down the entire cluster as they are moved from failed worker to failed worker.  If your cluster is genuinely a bit unstable then you may want to increase this parameter three to a larger number like twenty.  You should change the `~/.dask/config` file on the machine that hosts your scheduler to include the following value :

```
allowed-failures: 20
```

Currently in dask/distributed master you can also assign this with the environment variable `DASK_ALLOWED_FAILURES=20`.  This should be available in the release following 1.15.2.

Comment: OK thanks! It doesn't have to do with an "unstable cluster" it's just that allowing jobs to be killed under certain circumstances increases the priority of the job being dispatched. Hence having jobs dying and being recovered and re-run might be a good scenario in my case.

I don't think that the "allowed-failures" will work in this case. I think the possibility of turning a "KilledWorker" into from "error" to "lost" such that the scheduler can re-launch the job will do the trick.

I will check the github issue such that I can help if needed.

shareeditdeleteflag

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found the root of the problem:

If I'm not wrong dask/distributed uses the `__sizeof__` attribute to plan the deployment of objects in a worker.

If this is true, as the specification of `__sizeof__` states
"Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to." (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) distributed might be underestimating the size of the objects such as sparse matrices or third-party classes that might contain arrays or other large objects sent to a worker and getting my cluster scheduler (e.g. Torque) to kill the worker.

maybe the correct way of solving it would be to recommend adding a dask-specific method for computing the size instead of relying on sys.getsizeof?